# Sorting and categorising data from database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, sorting

I am in need of a way to categories big amount (roughly 120 or more values) of data coming from a database. Nothing much comes to mind so I have decided to ask here. I would need a `C#` or `SQL` solution (or at least tips on it).

Data that needs to be sorted currently is in one column, but I am open to any suggestions. An example of the data is below:

```
- A2-11 (Main branch that contains all A2 from below)
- A2-113
- A2-114
- A2-115
- .
- .
- .
- F-L-5 (Main branch)
- F-L-55 (Another branch in there)
- F-L-56 (Contains all values below)
- F-L-566 
- F-L-567
- .
- .
- .
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Could be displayed as an example, small tree diagram:

[TreeExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMsJS.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try custom OrderBy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication50
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));


            string[] data =  { "Main-A2-11", "Main-A2-113", "Main-A2-114", "Main-A2-115",
                              "Third-F-L-56", "Third-F-L-566", "Third-F-L-567",
                              "Second-F-L-5", "Second-F-L-55"
                            };

            foreach (string d in data)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { d });
            }

            dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Category").Contains("-") ? 
                     x.Field<string>("Category").Substring(0,x.Field<string>("Category").IndexOf("-")) :
                     x.Field<string>("Category"))
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => new SortRecord(y,"Category"))).SelectMany(x => x).CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
    public class SortRecord : IComparer<SortRecord >, IComparable<SortRecord>
    {
        string[] rowSplitArray;
        int length = 0;
        public SortRecord(DataRow x, string name)
        {
            rowSplitArray = x.Field<string>(name).Split(new char[] { '-' });
            length = rowSplitArray.Length;
        }


        public int Compare(SortRecord  rowA, SortRecord rowB)
        {

            int len = Math.Min(rowA.length, rowB.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (rowA.rowSplitArray[i] != rowB.rowSplitArray[i])
                    return rowA.rowSplitArray[i].CompareTo(rowB.rowSplitArray[i]);
            }

            return rowA.length.CompareTo(rowB.length);

        }
        public int CompareTo(SortRecord row)
        {
            return Compare(this, row);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have just realised that it doesn't completely answer my question. Your solution sorts the data, however, I also want to categorise it. My data will not have "Main", "Second", nor anything else, but the format given : 
 - F-L-56;  
 - F-L-566; 
 - F-L-567;

How could I use what you have already written (@jdweng) and categorise in a way where the main branch would hold F-L-56, which holds F-L-566 and F-L-567.  

Could visualise it as sub menus in a menu.

Comment: I was expecting you to make this additional request.  Already had the answer.  Updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a [Hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference)?
David

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to achieve the result but if you need to decide the performance as well then follow this article.[What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

you can certainly use hierarchyid in sql. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server

[This](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-performance-of-traversing-a-sql-hierarchy/) might help i guess.